# Center in relation to the Centralizer

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So let $G$ be a group and let $Z(G)$ be the centre of that group.

I know that $Z(G)$ is a subgroup of $G$

I also know that the centralizer $C(a)$ where $a\in G$ is also a subgroup of $G$

I also know that $Z(G) \subseteq C(a)$ for any $a \in G$

My question is

Does this mean that $Z(G)$ is also a subgroup of $C(a)$ for any $a \in G$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This follows from the following more general fact:

Let $G$ be a group. If $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$ and $K \subseteq H$, then $K$ is a subgroup of $H$.

Comment: yes, I was just making sure , thanks